# Want to get data to be shown in a listview conditionally

Tags: xamarin

In Xamarin Forms, I have a listview that shows all the items of the item table. I want to show only the items that have the 'status' approved. how can I do this? where do I pass the 'where status = 'approved'' condition.

This is my XAML Code:

```
    <ViewModels:ItemViewModel/>

</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}"

          HasUnevenRows="True" 
          x:Name="lstItems"
         ItemTapped="LstItems_OnItemTapped">





    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <ViewCell>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemCode}" TextColor="Blue"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding ItemDesc}"  TextColor="Blue"/>


                </StackLayout>

            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>


    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

**My View Model is as below:**

namespace MyFirstDbApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List _itemsList;

```
    public List<Item> ItemsList



    {
        get { return _itemsList; }

        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ItemViewModel()
    {

        InitializeDataAsync();
    }


    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {

        var ItemServices = new ItemServices();

        ItemsList = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync();

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

**Errors on implementing my new code:**

**var result = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(); 
 ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.Status == "Approved"**

Line:1 -An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property ItemServices.GetItemsAsync

Line:1-No Overload For Method 'ConfigureAwait' takes 0 argurments

Line:2-Cannot Convert SourceType 'Systems.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable ' To Target Type 'System.
Colelction.GenericList '

Comment: Just filter the list base on your criteria. What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: I have added my xaml code in the question itself. That returns all the items in my sql to the listview. I want to show only a few items in the listview conditionaly. How and where do i pass the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering should be done on the ItemsList in your ViewModel, not in XAML.

```
_viewModel.ItemsList.Where(x => x.Status == "Approved");
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Hey there! I am very new to xamarin development. I have added my ViewModel Code also in the question. Can u please also tell me where to add your code in my view model? Thank you so much...

Comment: in InitializeDataAsync..

var result = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait();
ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.Status == "Approved");

Comment: I have errors showing up for the code. Mentioned in my question.Can u pls explain how to go about with it. Will be of great help. Pls.

Comment: var result = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.Status == "Approved").ToList();

this is pretty basic c#

Comment: Np! Accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: can u please help me with this problem of mine? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118735/how-to-access-a-variable-in-my-homepage-in-my-viewmodel-class

Comment: It is just an extension of the code with which you helped me a few hours back. (x => x.Status == "Approved")... Here I want to pass (x=>x.ItemCode==="something").. now this something is a variable in the homepage and i want to access in my view model. Please help me do it