# How to access a variable in my homepage in my ViewModel Class?

Tags: xamarin

I have build a xamarin project which populates a list of items in a listview on the homepage. I need to pass a variable on this page to the ViewModel class. How do i do that??? Help will be appreciated.

**My Home page code is as below:**

private async void LstItems_OnItemTapped(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e )

```
    {
        var ItemCodeParam = e.Item as Item;

         var ItemCode = ItemCodeParam.ItemCode;

         await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailItemPage(ItemCode));
```

I need to pass the **ItemCode** to my ViewModel Class.

```
    }
```

**My View Model is as below**

namespace MyFirstDbApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List _itemsList;

```
    public List<Item> ItemsList



    {
        get { return _itemsList; }

        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ItemDetailsViewModel()
    {

        InitializeDataAsync();
    }


    private async Task InitializeDataAsync()
    {






        var result = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.ItemCode == "").ToList();


    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you create your VM?  Just pass the value into it's constructor, or set a property.

Comment: I am really sorry to ask you this. But can u pls tell me how to do it in coding??? I have included my VM code in the question. I need to pass the ItemCode from my home page to the VM 
ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.ItemCode == "").ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
public ItemDetailsViewModel(string ItemCode)
{
    InitializeDataAsync(ItemCode);
}

private async Task InitializeDataAsync(string code)
{
    var result = await ItemServices.GetItemsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    ItemsList = result.Where(x => x.ItemCode == code).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I got an exception thrown which says: An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

are u sure I do not have to write any code on the home page??

Comment: I assume that you are creating your VM when your DetailItemPage loads?  Are you passing the parameter to the ItemDetailsViewModel constructor when you create it?

Comment: No. I have not created a VM when the DetailItemPage loads. I only call the DetailItemPage on the item_tapped event of the listview on my homepage.Please help me do it. I simply wrote the code that u gave above. A newbie to MVVM concept. Got no idea how to go about with it. Will be really kind of you to help me out with this.

Comment: When/where do you create your VM?

Comment: I am sorry but I have not created it anywhere. I created a class called ItemDetailsViewModel and the code inside is handwritten. I acess my data from my services class wherein i have written the code to get my data using REST API. And i have bound the listview on the DetailItemPage with this View Model

 <ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <ViewModels:ItemDetailsViewModel/>

    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is Jason's answer (pass object as a parameter in the constructor of your *ItemDetailsViewModel()* class. The error you specified in the first comment is because your code requires a single parameter-less constructor for it to work. Also I think in the code example that Jason specified you need to add the *await* keyword in front of the *InitializeDataAsync(ItemCode)* method.

Now, when you're ready to start implementing a MVVM design pattern, I would suggest using IoC container to store your persistent objects. TinyIoC is great for that. If you'll use a MVVM framework, I recommend FreshMVVM (for Xamarin Forms) which includes TinyIoC in the nuget package.